# Query results from two list related to each other

Tags: apex, soql, query

Suppose I have in my org those Contact records:

```
1) FirstName = 'Ross', LastName = 'Geller'
2) FirstName = 'Rachel', LastName = 'Green'
3) FirstName = 'Monica', LastName = 'Geller'
4) FirstName = 'Ross', LastName = 'Green'
```

and somebody, in an apex method, passes me those two lists:

```
List<String> firstNameList = new List<String>{'Ross', 'Rachel'};
List<String> lastNameList = new List<String>{'Geller', 'Green'};
```

is there a way to query only the "desired" contacts? ('Ross Geller' and 'Rachel Green')

If I do:

```
List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, firstName, LastName from Contact where FirstName in :firstNameList and LastName in :lastNameList];
```

I get:

```
Ross Geller
Rachel Green
Ross Green
```

If I do:

```
List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, firstName, LastName from Contact where FirstName in :firstNameList or LastName in :lastNameList];
```

I get:

```
Ross Geller
Rachel Green
Monica Geller
Ross Green
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a formula field

```
FullName__c = FirstName  + " "+ LastName
```

2) Then in your apex code create a third list:

```
List<String> fullNameList = new List<String>();
for(Integer i=0;i<firstNameList.size();i++){
    fullNameList.add(firstNameList[i] + ' '+ lastNameList[i]);
}

List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, firstName, LastName from Contact where FullName__c in :fullNameList]
```

Comment: SOQL "[selectivity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm)" errors forthcoming... To avoid future problems, `FullName__c = :fullNameList AND FirstName = :firstNameList AND LastName = :lastNameList`.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox I totally missed it. :)